# How to create non-point feature manually?

Tags: arcgis-pro, features, overlapping-features

How to create a non-point feature manually on a map in ArcGIS Pro? For example, a small area as in the yellow shape in the image attached.

[image]

I would like to later be able to use the feature to extract contour values of the underlying layer to a table.

Comment: Did you look arcpro help ? This seem to cover the subject https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/editing/create-polygon-features.htm

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else with a similar query, this was my solution: I used the following page https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/editing/get-started-editing.htm to create an independent feature, polygon drawn freehand, and then clipped my layer of interest.